# Feliz Ano Novo 2020!

Tags: suporte

Muito obrigado a [@Augusto Vasques](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/137387/augusto-vasques) pela tradução.

---

O ano que passou foi movimentado e bastante difícil para a comunidade assim como para empresa. Este ano, concluímos com sucesso algumas iniciativas incrivelmente importantes:

Discutimos e adicionamos artigos sobre "[Os valores da comunidade](/help/key-values)" e o "[Manifesto](/help/manifesto)" na Central de Ajuda.
Realizamos alguns concursos
e muito mais! Que continuemos assim!

#### Esse ano traduzido em números

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | Stack Overflow     |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    | em Português       |  em Português     |
|                    | 2018               |  2019             |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Perguntas         |     45 234         |    42 304         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Respostas         |     38 855         |    30 678         |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Novos Usuários    |     32 417         |    35 836         |
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### Algumas reflexões sobre o futuro

- *Mais atenção ao feedback do usuário*. Como podemos ver, [a empresa seguiu um curso mais ousado](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/) buscando melhorar a experiência de participação no site. É muito importante que façamos melhorias com base no feedback da comunidade. Embora tenhamos contado com as ideias dos usuários para tomar decisões desde o primeiro dia, este ano haverá ainda mais oportunidades para compartilhar seus pensamentos sobre o site. Se você já pensou em mudar algo no site, parece ser um ótimo momento para implementar seus planos!
- *Webcasts, encontros, concursos* e outras iniciativas para "criar uma comunidade". Eu acho que seria ótimo realizar mais eventos desse tipo no ano novo.
- *Foco na missão do projeto*. Se conseguirmos evitar efetivamente tudo (bom ou ruim) que está tentando mudar o foco de nossa missão (criar uma base de conhecimento da comunidade), o site crescerá mais rápido e a experiência de participação será ainda mais agradável. Uma maneira de conseguir isso é escolher um objetivo ambicioso e, juntos, fazermos todo o possível para alcançá-lo.

Na última década, o mundo da TI mudou muito: em 2010, demoravam-se vários dias para descobrir como criar um projeto “Hello World!” para a primeira versão do sistema operacional Android, hoje é possível escrever um aplicativo para um veículo em JavaScript que transmite música de uma rede social em poucas horas. A própria comunidade também mudou. Em todos os aspectos. Estou extremamente satisfeito por perceber que, durante 6 anos, todos nós fomos um catalisador para essas mudanças 100% positivas. Muito obrigado a todos nós por isso! =)

#### Stack Overflow somos nós! Vamos nos parabenizar um ao outro!

Junte-se as celebrações! Compartilhe os eventos positivos mais agradáveis da vida comunitária que você pessoalmente se lembra. Se durante o último ano alguns usuários melhoraram sua vida, não hesite em parabenizá-los dizendo-lhes "obrigado" em uma resposta a esta pergunta. Estou certo de que os usuários ficarão muito contentes com sua atenção.

[image: Christmas Tree]

*Muito obrigado a todos os usuários do [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)! Feliz Ano Novo! Desejamos a todos o melhor e teremos o maior prazer em ver todos no Ano Novo! Há muitas coisas interessantes esperando por todos nós! =)*

Answer (score 19):

*This is not a thank you, they are questions that I sincerely hope are officially read and answered by the company.*

> Esse ano traduzido em números...

```
 -------------------------------------------------------------
|                    | Stack Overflow     |  Stack Overflow   |
|                    | em Português       |  em Português     |
|                    | 2018               |  2019             |
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Perguntas         |     45 234         |    42 304         |  -6.47%
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Respostas         |     38 855         |    30 678         |  -21.04%
|--------------------|--------------------|-------------------|
|  Novos Usuários    |     32 417         |    35 836         |  10.54%
 -------------------------------------------------------------
```

- Caiu o número de perguntas;
- Caiu drasticamente o número de respostas;
- Aumentou o número de usuários;

Como a empresa analisa esses números? Foi um ano bom? Ruim? Atingiu as metas esperadas?

Na minha análise, o fato de os números de 2019 serem piores que o de 2018 mostra que o que foi feito durante 2019 não funcionou. Tem mais pessoas e mesmo assim menos conteúdo? Tem algo muito errado. E a qualidade de tudo isso? Aumentou? Diminuiu? E o número de visitas anônimas?

> Mais atenção ao feedback do usuário.

Em 2019 a SE tentou algumas poucas vezes "ouvir" o usuário e nada mudou. O site continua com os mesmos problemas que iniciou 2019 e conseguiu desenvolver novos ou até agravar os existentes. O que será diferente em 2020? Só dizer que será diferente não faz ser diferente. Poderia listar tudo o que a empresa pretende fazer?

> É muito importante que façamos melhorias com base no feedback da comunidade.

Mas antes precisam aprender a receber o feedback. E não, abrir perguntas avulsas no Meta solicitando "sugestões" não é receber feedback.

> Se você já pensou em mudar algo no site, parece ser um ótimo momento para implementar seus planos!

O nosso Meta está cheio de ideias e discussões. Espero que a empresa já tenha tirado um tempo para ler todo esse conteúdo. Quais foram as ideias que vocês gostaram e que pretendem implementar em 2020?

> Webcasts, encontros, concursos e outras iniciativas para "criar uma comunidade". Eu acho que seria ótimo realizar mais eventos desse tipo no ano novo.

E quem vai organizar? Como a empresa pretende "criar uma comunidade" se ela mesma não participa ativamente?

> Foco na missão do projeto.

A empresa precisa melhorar muito antes de querer prometer um "foco" definido.

> Se conseguirmos evitar efetivamente tudo (bom ou ruim) que está tentando mudar o foco de nossa missão (criar uma base de conhecimento da comunidade), o site crescerá mais rápido e a experiência de participação será ainda mais agradável.

A comunidade fez sua parte em 2019. A empresa fez a sua? Qual foi a parte da empresa e como isso impactou na comunidade?

> Uma maneira de conseguir isso é escolher um objetivo ambicioso e, juntos, fazermos todo o possível para alcançá-lo.

Então existe um "juntos"? Em 2019 houve apenas "a comunidade" dado que a empresa foi completamente omissa em todos os quesitos. Como pretendem construir o "juntos"?

Fora isso, em vários momentos você, Nicolas, disse que prefere o modo "ouvinte" ao invés da pró-atividade em pról da comunidade. Prefere que os problemas aconteçam, que os usuários relatem à SE junto com as propostas de melhorias e a empresa decide **o que** fazer, **quando** fazer e **se** for fazer, sem nenhum tipo de *feedback* à comunidade. Isso não funcionou em 2018, não funcionou em 2019. Você pretende mudar isso ou no final de 2020 teremos mais uma "mensagem de ano novo" pedindo mais pro-atividade da comunidade enquanto os problemas se perpetuam no site?

Comment: Não gosto de comentários *me too*, mas no meta em certas postagens é importante dar apoio nominal mais que apenas o voto.

Comment: @Maniero _me too!_  E sobre o "curso mais ousado", considerando que já deve ter ficado bem claro pra qualquer um que acompanha o site que não está dando certo, quando podemos voltar ao site que realmente funcionava? Vocês lembram? Aquele site antigo, beeem lá do começo, que foi o que fez sucesso e reputação boa, que agradava o pessoal mais sério, profissionais experientes e amadores engajados, e desagradava basicamente quem não agregava, aquele perfeito mecanismo de seleção natural que transformou a rede em referência confiável que é o que ainda, apesar de tudo, mantem o site no topo.

Comment: PS: Não achem que eu não sei que page views dão retorno e são "prova de sucesso imediato", mas chega uma hora que por falta de conteúdo bom, os page views acabam.

Comment: @Maniero *me too*. Nem é preciso dizer mais nada.

Comment: *Me too*. Só acho um pouco injusto o parágrafo final citando o Nicolas pessoalmente. Não sei o que ele pensa sobre isso, mas nesta postagem (e na seguinte) parece que ele está apenas reproduzindo o discurso oficial da empresa.

Comment: @bfavaretto Porque a ideia é justamente saber a opinião dele sobre isso. Em vários outros momentos eu questionei isso a ele e a resposta foi que ele preferia a administração passiva, aguardando que fôssemos a ele com tudo pronto. Isso é uma característica dele em administrar a comunidade, não necessariamente reproduz o discurso da empresa.

Comment: Notifico o meu apoio. Me too.

Comment: @Woss Pode ser, deve mesmo ter uma parte que é característica dele, mas na maneira dele atuar eu também vejo muito reflexo do momento atual da SE e de como ela foi "evoluindo".

Comment: Pelo que ando vendo ultimamente, especialmente no metão, sobre as perspectivas e políticas implantadas pela SE e a interação da SE com a comunidade, a conclusão é que nós precisamos encontrar um outro site urgentemente.

Comment: @VictorStafusa ficou aquela situação da molecada jogando bola com praticamente todo mundo se dando bem, mas a bola é justo do moleque mimado e teimoso que faz questão de contrariar todo mundo. Ou a molecada arruma outra bola, ou atura o moleque pra poder jogar, fazer o que...

Comment: *Me too*, a 100%.

Comment: _Me 2._ No entanto, eu não vejo mais porque continuarmos apontando os erros e dúvidas para a SE sendo que eles não demonstram nenhum interesse em resposta. O que temos é que estão "cuidando disso", "cientes" e/ou "sob controle" mas é o que os números apontaram. Acho muito irônico um _feliz ano novo_ tão feliz e ingrato para uma comunidade em crise de qualidade.

Comment: @VictorStafusa uma comunidade gerida pela comunidade. Não é o que era para ser as redes da SE? E se migrarmos, o que acontecerá com o SOpt? E o conteúdo já aqui? Roubaríamos para "o novo"? Iniciaríamos do zero? Seria uma "ofensiva" contra a SE, clonar nosso conteúdo para um local onde podemos ter controle total sob ele.

Comment: @CypherPotato Não sei nada sobre isso. A única coisa que sei é que a administração da SE de hoje "*perdeu a sua alma*" e que o futuro das comunidades sob essa administração é sombrio.

Answer (score 12):

> - *Mais atenção ao feedback do usuário*. Como podemos ver, [a empresa seguiu um curso mais ousado](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/) buscando melhorar a experiência de participação no site. É muito importante que façamos melhorias com base no feedback da comunidade. Embora tenhamos contado com as ideias dos usuários para tomar decisões desde o primeiro dia, este ano haverá ainda mais oportunidades para compartilhar seus pensamentos sobre o site. Se você já pensou em mudar algo no site, parece ser um ótimo momento para implementar seus planos!

Essa é a pior forma de feedback que já vi sendo implantada na SE. Ela oferece exatamente zero de transparência e não permite aos usuários trocar experiências. E permitir aos usuários trocar experiências é muito importante para permitir que com um diálogo saudável, eles possam alinhar expectativas e entender melhor como o site funciona ou deveria funcionar ou quais são as boas ideias de melhorias que deveriam ser levadas à administração e quais são aquelas que deveriam ser descartadas.

O meta existe e funciona. Não é perfeito, tem várias deficiências, mas funciona. Por outro lado, esse "loop" aí apenas troca um instrumento que embora imperfeito, ainda é democrático e transparente por algo que é totalmente fechado e totalitário e que não tem nenhuma garantia de ser melhor.

> - *Webcasts, encontros, concursos* e outras iniciativas para "criar uma comunidade". Eu acho que seria ótimo realizar mais eventos desse tipo no ano novo.

Isso daí é algo que dificilmente afetará mais do que 0,1% da comunidade. O efeito disso seria lamentavelmente negligível.

> - *Foco na missão do projeto*. Se conseguirmos evitar efetivamente tudo (bom ou ruim) que está tentando mudar o foco de nossa missão (criar uma base de conhecimento da comunidade), o site crescerá mais rápido e a experiência de participação será ainda mais agradável. Uma maneira de conseguir isso é escolher um objetivo ambicioso e, juntos, fazermos todo o possível para alcançá-lo.

E qual é o "objetivo ambicioso"? Os moderadores e usuários comuns já estão aqui trabalhando de graça para vocês, logo eu esperaria que a SE ao menos os valorizasse, mas o que vejo acontecendo é justamente o oposto. Além disso, essas palavras são vazias, pois para crescer o que precisamos é de mecanismos para mitigar os problemas que existem no site e o que vejo sendo implementado tem pouca ou nenhuma relação com isso. Muitos usuários experientes ou deixaram o site ou diminuíram bastante a participação (inclusive eu). Não há mais muita motivação para se participar aqui e não vejo nenhuma ação da SE em tentar atuar nesse sentido.

Comment: `o site crescerá mais rápido` isto mostra um certo desespero para aumentar o volume sem falar abertamente que qualidade não importa mais. Inclusive porque já tem pressão por resultados financeiros e há especulações que estão se preparando para a venda. Vão negar, mas quase tudo que negam acaba se comprovando depois. Não há mais interesse em fazer o que o site foi criado inicialmente e só números importam. Nem falo tanto dos internacionais. Pleo menos o SOpt está largado. E ele deve ter mais problemas que os demais. E pra falar a verdade não vejo solução sem uma mudança radical na plataforma.