# A SE considera que é um problema o fato de quase 40% das perguntas de 2019 terem sido fechadas?

Tags: debate, perguntas-fechadas

Aproveitando que foram colocados alguns números de 2019 ([aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8115/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8110/112052)), segue um questionamento sobre um ponto específico.

Segundo os números acima, em 2019 tivemos 42304 perguntas, sendo que 16594 delas foram fechadas. Quer dizer que 39,22% das perguntas feitas em 2019 foram fechadas. Pois é, **quase 40% das perguntas** fechadas. Não sei vocês, mas eu acho muita coisa...

Isso porque não há muitos usuários com pontuação >= 3000 usando seus [votos de fechamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Atualmente, [há menos de 300 usuários com esta pontuação](https://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/1176227/usuarios-com-reputacao-suficiente-para-fechar-perguntas), mas não sei se todos estão usando os seus votos (minha percepção, vendo o dia-a-dia, é que a maioria destes não está sequer acessando o site).

<sup>*Aqui faço um mea-culpa, pois ultimamente não estou com tanto tempo disponível para me dedicar ao site, então eu também estou nesse grupo que não está fechando tudo que deveria...*</sup>

Ou seja, se tivéssemos mais usuários dando votos de fechamento, a porcentagem de perguntas fechadas ficaria bem acima dos 40% (talvez até passando os 50%, dada a quantidade assustadora de perguntas ruins e fora do escopo que tem surgido ultimamente). O fato é que há mais perguntas a serem fechadas do que pessoas para fazê-lo. Isso faz com que muita coisa ruim continue aberta, por muitas vezes recebendo respostas igualmente ruins e até mesmo recebendo votos positivos (o que passa a mensagem errada de que qualidade não é importante - eu espero que ainda seja). E se não fossem os moderadores (que fecharam 3 vezes mais do que os usuários não-moderadores), a situação seria ainda pior.

Daí vem os meus questionamentos:

- a SE considera que é um problema termos tantas perguntas fechadas?
- em caso afirmativo, o que está sendo feito para resolvê-lo? Pois a comunidade não está sendo suficiente para lidar com o problema (na prática só enxugamos gelo). Creio que a interface do site poderia ajudar a guiar o usuário (mais ou menos como sugerido [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803), por exemplo), mas em vez disso vemos somente [mudanças com efeito duvidoso](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8120/112052) sendo implementadas. Gostaria de saber se há mais medidas a serem tomadas para que tenhamos mais perguntas de qualidade e dentro do escopo.

Comment: Lá para Janeiro de 2021 respondem-te eheheh. O problema é que a SE quer seguir o caminho contrário, mais conteúdo e mais visitas e pouco interessa a qualidade. Claro que vão negar isso, mas está a vista de todos.

Comment: @JorgeB. De fato, ultimamente todas as ações da empresa indicam isso. Só queria que admitissem que é isso (ou então que não é mas não sabem como resolver), mas em vez disso nunca respondem nada...

Comment: è bom notar que a maioria foram fechadas por ser fora de escopo (motivo criado pela comunidade) e depois não estar clara. Tem um pouco de duplicata também. Eu tenho tentando evitar marcar duplicata quando a pergunta é ruim demais. Hoje o que mais ocorre é um destes casos: "preciso fazer algo e quero que façam para mim", "quero uma dica, luz, norte, tutorial, material de estudo, explicação completa", "postei esse erro e mais nada, como resolver?", "tenho esse código e está dando erro, como conserto?", "sei que está errado, vou postar algo mas não vou dar contexto algum, me ajuda aí",

Comment: "postei todo meu código, se vira pra me ajudar", "postei, não tenho uma pergunta e qualquer ajuda é válida". E depois das pessoas tentarem ajudar, depois de um muito ruído, normalmente o resultado é que não dá para responder bem, e mesmo nos casos que sai uma resposta em geral ela não é boa. E mesmo quando sai algo que realmente é boa para o autor, não  serve para outras pessoas. Até algumas pessoas que não gostavam dos fechamentos antes hoje se revolta com a atitude das pessoas que elas tentam salvar.

Comment: Os que não se revoltam é porque não participam muito da comunidade e não perceber o tamanho do problema. Justamente porque poucas pessoas votam para fechar os moderadores tem que fazê-lo. Algumas pessoas quase nunca votam, mesmo participando. Não é que elas acham que estão tudo bom, elas só decidiram não fazer, em geral porque sabem que isso cria um karma ruim, elas não querem ser mal vistas por essas pessoas, preferem ser mal vistas por não fazerem sua parte na comunidade. Em geral são pessoas que tem o compromisso com o erro. Claro, tem casos e casos.

Comment: Mesmo quando as pessoas participam do fechamento, chegar a 5 demora muito e é tarde demais. Se todo mundo que fosse responder fosse crítico e só respondesse quando a pergunta está boa fechar rápido nem seria necessário, mas isto não vai acontecer nunca. Concordo que se tivesse mais participação o fechamento talvez chegaria a 60 ou 70%, a qualidade está bem ruim mesmo. Tem casos que eu vejo que está ruim mas deixo para a comunidade quando não é tão ruim e tem alguns votos. Por outro lado e fecharia menos se tivesse mais votos negativos.

Comment: Admito que tem caso que eu queria mais negativar, mas só posso dar 40 votos por dia, costuma ter o dobro disso de perguntas ruins. Claro que fecho quando vejo que tem um problema, mas em muitos casos eu poderia deixar aberto e só negativar, dando mais chance pra comunidade de manifestar. Mas não tenho votos suficiente. Mas não é só isto, precisaria a comunidade se manifestar mais com negativos quando não está bom. Pra mim perguntas ruins negativas já está bom se não for grave, mesmo tanto uma resposta ruim, ela também seria negativada e tudo ficaria bem,

Comment: a pessoa recebe uma resposta oficial (mesmo fechada a pessoa pode receber uma resposta nos comentários), fica contente, mesmo que a resposta lhe prejudique e o conteúdo some e não prejudica outras pessoas. Falta comunidade fazendo mais isso e o sistema todo não ajuda. Vou destacar essa resposta https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8117/101. Não concordo com 100% dela, acho que a avaliação é um pouco errada em pontos específicos, nos detalhes (talvez por conhecer pouco a comunidade ou uma visão um pouco limitada da história da nossa educação, a coisa é pior :)), mas a essência está correta.

Comment: Não há compromisso das pessoas com seu aprendizado, com sua pergunta, nada. Não busco perguntas totalmente virtuosas, mas não pode ser tão ruins. O sistema não está preparado para lidar com tal volume de coisa ruim. E chegou no ponto que realmente algo deveria começar fechado e depois abrir quando merece, mas sei que isto é utópico. Está difícil produzir sinal com tanto ruído, se gasta tempo demais com idiossincrasias de cada usuário, e cada um tem a sua. Funcionava quando os usuários tinha que lidar com a idiossincrasia da comunidade, havia unidade. Algo precisa ser feito.

Comment: Toda sensação é que a SE não quer fazer nada mais, só deixar rolar e quem sabe fazer coisas para as pessoas desistirem da qualidade sem anunciar isto oficialmente. Se eles acham que não estão fazendo isto estão vivendo em uma realidade paralela. Acho que aqui temos mais problemas, mas é meio generalizado nos sites de TI. Tem caso pior em fechamento e % fechado dos mods. O entendimento geral é que a SE não tem mais visão do que fazer.  Não respondi porque acho que isso é pra SE apenas responder.

Comment: Um detalhe importante é que eu tenho certeza que a SE acha que é um problema. Mas não sabemos qual problema. Se tem muita coisa ruim deveria fechar mais ainda e o problema é ter tanta coisa ruim, ou mesmo tendo tanta coisa ruim, fechar é o problema.

Comment: @hkotsubo a query deu 295 usuários com ou mais de 3000 pontos de reputação. Eu estimo de que sejam um 25 usuários ativos comprometidos com o bom andamento do site.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Eu tentei fazer uma query pra ver quantos deram algum voto de fechamento em 2019, mas desisti. De qualquer forma, essa informação é apenas um complemento que não considero essencial, pois o ponto principal da pergunta é a porcentagem de perguntas fechadas

Comment: @bfavaretto ao certo qual a percentagem? Isso diz muito da qualidade das mesmas. Com esses dados não há motivo para achar estranho os mods fecharem tantas perguntas, até deviam era fechar mais. Se uma pergunta acaba excluída devia estar fechada com toda a certeza. Se fossem boas, por mais que se fechassem não seriam excluídas.

Comment: @JorgeB. Excluí o comentário anterior porque estava errado, não é mais da metade. Mas é muito. Cerca de 46% de excluídas criadas em 2019 (contra ~40% das criadas em 2018).

Comment: @bfavaretto dá para colocar esses números de todos os anos?! Só para ver a evolução?

Comment: Se considerar que uns 70~80% são helpdesk individual inútil para outra pessoa...

Comment: 90% de qualquer coisa é porcaria. E olhando as perguntas que aparecem no site, só 40% ter sido fechado é pouco. Faço o *mea culpa* por não participar mais nisso, mas em grande parte é porque já perdi a fé e a confiança na SE.

Comment: https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1217838950494228480  isso explica muita coisa. Tem outras coisas que dá pra acompanhar a saga. Muita gente está saindo desde o ano passado. Parece que a empresa se tornou bem tóxica pra todo mundo.

Answer (score -6):

I will appreciate the translation of this answer.

---

Is it a problem that many questions get closed? Yes, it *definitely* is a problem. Moreover I see two consequent questions in your post:

1. How to make more users moderate the site?
2. How to increase quality of questions?

Let us take a closer look at the situation with a tiny story.

#### The Stack Overflow in Russian experience

My friend and I launched hashcode.ru in 2010, with one goal in mind - effectively accumulate knowledge about programming and share our findings with others. Our Q&A site was quite simple: no closing queues, moderator elections, chats, etc. Only asking and answering. The entire project team consisted of one-person-orchestra (me), who was developing the site, administrating a server, selling ads on the site, etc. The "outside world" was very rude and negative to the project, because it was a "clone" of Stack Overflow. Despite all that, our community was a happy one: we concentrated on the most important thing - creating knowledge on programming. The whole community *together* maintained a so called "atmosphere of knowledge" on the site, there was no drama, everything that was not related to programming or moderation of the community was deleted.

We were lucky and one day we became part of a much bigger movement, the community migrated to the Stack Exchange platform. As part of the network, we got a good infrastructure: the best in the world Q&A engine, chats, moderator elections, Winter Bashes, etc. The site has become more popular and the popularity showed a flip side — it seems that we have become less happy: we got dramas, showdowns, some users constantly were complaining about something...

> ...
>   We want more and more, but life goes by
>   We just forgot how to be happy alive.
>   ...

— [Lumen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumen_(band)).

I think, one gets the greatest pleasure from Stack Overflow by creating value for others, getting to know incredibly talented colleagues, and having a chance to learn something new every day. I personally cannot find the variable “number of new engine features” in the equation of my happiness being on the site.

#### Make more users close questions or make more users help moderate the site

Let’s be honest, we are on the site because we love programming, we want to see the same minded people and their answers, and interesting questions to answer ourselves. I refuse to believe that some of us might want to see more closed questions as the ultimate goal. Instead, I think we want to see more useful and interesting questions, and the more (both interesting and useful) the better.

Asking questions is hard. Asking good questions is twice harder. On early days of Stack Overflow in Russian the most active folks from the community had been looking at each question on the site and editing it if it was needed. Let me emphasis: *editing each question if an improvement was needed to bring it in line with community standards, not closing*. Why? Because we felt we need to lead by example: Want to have more good questions? Be the positive changing force! Ask your question or improve somebody’s one! Show people your passion about the quality by improving the content, lead by example. I haven’t really seen any other working solutions.

#### How to make the others be involved

We need to give our colleagues an opportunity to be involved:

- Be welcome and passionate about what we do here.
- Lead by example.
- Assist and guide others when they are in trouble.

If you close a question there is nothing that I can do. If you improve it, I can understand the mistakes I have made (if I have asked it) or share my knowledge (if I have an answer), stay on the site a little bit more and probably help to improve others’ questions in the future. Closing thoughts me away regardless if I want to ask or to answer.

#### How can we start changing the trend

A journey of ten thousand miles begins with a single step. One ends up being in nowhere if they do not know where they want to go. My bet is that if we start improving questions instead of closing them it will positively affect the quality of questions as well as the willingness of other people to stay on the site, follow the rules and be productive. To see how it goes we can track monthly edits, closings and answers after these actions (and report it on meta).

What do you think if we make "increasing the number of edits of questions" the main comprehensive goal of the community for this year?

---

P.S. Stack Exchange provides only the platform and a little bit of guidance. You are the Portuguese speaking software developers and only you can change for better the Portuguese speaking world.

Comment: As perguntas são fechadas por serem "fora de escopo", "não claras" ou "amplas". Como poderemos então melhorá-las? - *The questions are closed because they are "out of scope", "unclear" or "broad". How can we then improve them?*

Comment: Muitas são: "Estou com um problema, este é o meu código. Por favor ajudem-me!" - *Many are: "I have a problem, this is my code. Please help me!"*

Comment: As the previous comments said, the problem goes **far** beyond editing. Most questions are so unclear and poorly written that only the OP would be able to edit it in order to make it on topic, and we have no other option than closing it (because comments asking for clarification rarely work as well). When we don't close, it's not uncommon that it receives some bad, low quality answers (which is why we prefer to close as soon as possible in the first place).

Comment: Como já foi dito, o problema vai **muito** além de editar. Muitas perguntas são tão confusas que apenas o AP seria capaz de torná-la dentro do escopo, e a nós só resta a opção de fechar (pois comentários pedindo esclarecimentos raramente funcionam). Quando não fechamos, não é raro aparecer respostas ruins e de baixa qualidade (e é por isso que preferimos fechar o mais rápido possível).

Comment: Quem melhor pode melhorar a pergunta é quem a faz.  Nós podemos e queremos ajudar. No entanto, temos de ter melhores ferramentas para o fazer.. - *Who can best improve the question is who asks it. We can and we want to help. However, we must have better tools to do so.*

Comment: O que você acha de "prover melhores ferramentas para melhor ajudar a ter-mos melhores perguntas" ser  o principal objectivo do staff do SO para este ano? - *What do you think of "providing better tools to better help us have better questions" is the main goal of SO staff this year?*

Comment: *[The system should guide the user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803), so the questions - ideally, most of them, if not all - wouldn't need to be edited in the first place. **Why** things like that are never implemented? Why SE keeps asking us to do more than we already do?* - [O sistema deveria guiar o usuário](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314304/401803), assim as perguntas - idealmente - nem precisariam ser editadas. **Por que** coisas assim não são feitas? Por que insistem em pedir que nós façamos mais do que já fazemos?

Comment: @ramaral *Como poderemos então melhorá-las?* Você poderia fazer uma pergunta separada. Ficarei feliz em compartilhar alguns pensamentos.

Comment: @hkotsubo [Por favor, dê uma olhada neste tópico](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1225/6). Você poderia listar as ferramentas essenciais que você precisa para ter sucesso na construção da base de conhecimento que não temos agora?

Comment: Nicolas, em [Se você pudesse alterar QUALQUER coisa no site, o que mudaria?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8143/2541) encontrará algumas ideias. - *Nicolas, at [If you could change ANYTHING on the site, what would you change?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8143/2541) will find some ideas.*

Comment: @Nicolas I don't want to be aggressive. But this is small talk. Oh edit the questions is the solution... If SE had read our Meta since we had Gabe as CM you already know that the problem is another. Now days we have a big group of programmers that don't now even write in Portuguese and they want that we do the work for them. They don't debug the code, they don't effort to write a good question. We need frameworks to help this guys (like this: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7892/7210) and frameworks to help us to maintain this site (like this: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8143/7210)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky As the previous comments said, [here](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8143/2541) you'll find lots of ideas - more than 40 at the moment

Comment: `Because we felt we need to lead by example: Want to have more good questions? Be the positive changing force! Ask your question or improve somebody’s one!` Isto é o que chamamos chover no molhado. Todos sabem disto, todos faziam isto. Quando o volume de problemas ficou grande as pessoas não conseguiam fazer o tempo todo. As edições não conseguiam resolver o problema em muitos casos, as pessoas eram cada vez mais teimosas. As pessoas pararam de fazer isso ou se afastaram do site. Hoje as edições costumam resolver vírgulas e espaços e nada relevante porque é difícil resolver o problema de fato.

Comment: Me desculpe, mas a resposta parece enlatada (eu sei que não é, claro), e não entende nosso contexto. Já fizesses isto, cansou. Não sei na Rússia, mas no Brasil o nível de programadores entrando na área está muito baixo e as esmagadora maioria das perguntas são feitas por essas pessoas. Elas não são fracas em programação, isso nós podemos ajudar. Não podemos ajudar quem mal consegue se expressar. Falta o básico de matemática. Você edita, comenta e ela acha que todo mundo está errado só ela certa. O erro venceu o bom exemplo. Pode ser cultural. Raro algo que gere conhecimento real.

Comment: O nível de ruído ficou grande demais. A pessoas não tem mais a mesma vontade porque agora passam boa parte do tempo administrando os problemas do que ajudando com programação, exatamente o que você disse. Gastar mais tempo ainda com esses detalhes não melhora a situação. Piora quando a percepção é de que mesmo fazendo alguma coisa para melhorar a pergunta, cada vez vem mais coisa pior, não melhora, o exemplo não é percebido e aproveitado. A grosso modo de cada 10 mil novos usuário 1 acaba aproveitando bem o site.

Comment: @Maniero acho que não é cultural. Acho que é mesmo a nível mundial. Como a área está muito em voga em todo mundo e dá dinheiro, toda a gente quer ser programador. Para ser programador é preciso ter algumas bases, e a maioria que quer ser não as tem. Então fazem pelo copy e paste do que vêm na internet. Se tem de mudar uma "vírgula" e da erro vem logo para o SO fazer uma pergunta.

Comment: @JorgeB. eu até concordo, mas em alguns lugar fica pior. Se uma pessoa sabe duas línguas, excelente formação em ciências, tudo funciona bem na vida dela porque mora em um país que a norma é o acerto é diferente de quem sabe meia língua, mal entende aritmética, causa e efeito, e ela se acostuma com isso.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, você perguntou como melhorar. Eu fiz um requisição de recurso https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8132/devemos-diminuir-a-quantidade-de-votos-necess%c3%a1rios-para-fechar-e-reabrir-pergunt , o recurso está disponível tanto que foi implementado no SOEn, o que nos falta saber é se é possível o implementar de forma assimétrica, para adequá-lo a nossa realidade . Pelo que entendi o moderador perguntou a SE sobre as possibilidades técnicas mas até agora não recebeu resposta.

Comment: É interessante ver tudo isso com essa postagem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/342260/140010. Cada vez parece mais claro que a visão da SE se distancia do que as pessoas que fizeram isso dar certo tem de como o conteúdo deve ser produzido. A SE vem cometendo um erro atrás do outro no desespero do crescimento.