# Vale a pena permanecer no stackOverflow?

Tags: debate, pergunta-específica

Não posso acreditar que todo o meu esforço em fazer uma pergunta bem comentada seja fechada! Não acredito! Li como formatar uma pergunta adequadamente. Expliquei que é uma escolha de estado e cidade e que [após o uso do Ajax não consigo mais estanciar a classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430487). Não, não, não acredito que você fechou uma pergunta válida como essa.

Feito esse desabafo, acredito que não tenha mais o que fazer aqui nesse site.
Inúmeras perguntas "não qualificadas" em meu perfil demonstram minha falha em cumprir os vários requisitos impostos aqui para receber ajuda.

Acredito que o stackOverflow falhou em sua missão que é ajudar a quem precisa.

Ficaram presos a regras, pontos e virgulas e esqueceram do que importa. Da pessoa que está a quadro dias tentando acertar, e por falta de experiência ou burrice mesmo, não consegue. E olha que só coloquei nesse site pois já tentei 4 dias. Pois as vezes é uma variável escrita errada, uma virgula esquecida etc.
Não quero gastar o precioso tempo de vossas senhorias.

Mas como vocês não vão mudar, quem deve sair sou eu. Contudo acredito que ninguém vai sentir a minha falta. Agradeço aqueles que por bondade algum dia já tenham me ajudado. Mas quando não se consegue fazer uma pergunta! Ah.
Vou para outro site que aceite gente com pouca experiência como eu e sejam mais flexíveis. Saio daqui com um problema(simples para programadores experientes) mas difícil para os que não o são.

E se você leu até o final, obrigado.

Comment: Sobre "vocês não vão mudar", é questão de bom senso. Se você não for capaz de editar sua pergunta e seguir as observações, porque esperaria que o site inteiro trocasse os princípios básicos para te atender? É mera questão de lógica, você entra em um lugar, deve se adaptar a ele, e não o lugar a você. Veja por outro lado, se o site fosse meu, eu simplesmente deletaria um monte de lixo e faria uma prova de aptidão antes da pessoa fazer uma postagem (e com certeza seria um site com conteúdo melhor filtrado), mas eu simplesmente sigo regras também, porque o site não é meu.

Comment: Agora, para debater o assunto de maneira honesta, e envolvendo toda a comunidade, a pergunta foi migrada para o meta, conforme o colega @MarceloBoni sugeriu, assim não fica dependendo nem da minha nem da sua opinião. Só não esqueça que para o seu "incrivel esforço de fazer uma pergunta", a gente aqui da moderação em pleno domingo faz o "incrivel esforço" de analisar muitas postagens para identificar o problema delas e ainda apontar aonde está a solução para que o autor possa ser bem atendido (se ele vai ou não, opção dele de seguir a recomendação). E nem por isso a gente fica só se queixando.

Comment: Finalizando, sobre esta pergunta que fez, eu me faço a mesma todo dia. A conclusão que eu estou chegando é que não anda valendo não, mas quem tem que sair é a gente que se preocupa, e largar pra vocês transformarem isso aqui em mais um "(insira o nome com Y aqui) Respostas" (logo chega lá), assim todo mundo fica com o que merece. (tambem tenho direito de desabafar?). Agora, está em tempo de ler o que foi recomendado, editar a pergunta e ter a chance dela ser reaberta pela própria comunidade. Tem muita gente com todas as perguntas abertas e positivadas. Será que o problema é a moderação?

Comment: Todo dia isso, as mesmas reclamações, os mesmos alvos e as mesmas respostas à estes inúmeros desabafos.

Comment: Atualmente, não vale mais a pena. Por mais que você se dedique tanto quanto precisa para se adequar à estrutura do site e começar a usufruir de seus pontos positivos, só encontrará pessoas revoltadas e insatisfeitas "com as regras" tal como você está hoje. Se liberar as regras, vira bagunça e ninguém aproveita; se mantém as regras, não há recompensa em se ajustar à elas. Quanto mais cedo você encontrar outra forma de aprender, melhor. Se você não gostou da estrutura de como funciona o site mostra ainda mais como o site pode não ser adequado para você.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Acredito que a pergunta em questão seja essa aqui [classe PHP não carrega após uso do ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430487/classe-php-n%c3%a3o-carrega-ap%c3%b3s-uso-do-ajax).

Segue sua análise da questão mostrando o porque do motivo de fechamento.

---

A pergunta começa com seguinte texto:

> Após requisição Ajax classe PHP não aceita new. Um select ao lado do
>   outro. Quando escolho um estado, carrega cidades no outro select.
>
> A requisição ajax é enviada até a pagina pesquisa.php onde deveria
>   estanciar a classe Pesquisa acessar o bando de dados e guardar o array
>   na variável da classe. E posteriormente chamada na pagina onde estão
>   os selects, preenchendo o select das cidades. Mas na pagina
>   pesquisa.php ao tentar dar new Pesquisa() o deguguer entra em
>   suspensão parando tudo.

E em seguida vem um conjunto de códigos em PHP(PHP, HTML e JavaScript), que por sinal estão bem formatados e indentados que mostra realmente um capricho pessoal por parte do usuário com relação a pergunta.

**Mas só o capricho pessoal não transforma uma pergunta em uma boa pergunta.**

É preciso se colocar na posição de quem irá responder a sua pergunta e ter a consciência de que é preciso munir o autor da resposta com o máximo de informações relevantes. Informações essas que estão faltando na pergunta ou que tiveram o acesso dificultado pelo excesso de código não diretamente relacionado com o problema.

O problema com a questão começa com primeira frase:

> **"Após requisição Ajax classe PHP não aceita new."**

## Primeiro problema encontrado: A proporção do código com relação a erro

Eu tive que caçar no código onde se encontra o problema alegado. Lembrando que esse foi o meu primeiro contato com o código em questão.

[image: Proporção do código com relação a erro.]

Lembre-se, para você pode ser fácil navegar dentro de um código que tenha escrito e que esteja acostumado, mas para quem o analisa pela primeira vez não é uma tarefa fácil.
Pode ser alegado que havia um comentário indicando o erro, porém contra-argumento com a quantidade de código até o comentário e o os vazios cognitivos, com relação a questão,que o código não relato promove a quem estiver analisando.

## Segundo problema: não tem nenhuma mensagem ou log de erros anexado.

Mensagens e arquivos de log são muito úteis em análise. 
Na ciência da computação, um log de erros é um log de dado cujo o mesmo é um registro do erros críticos encontrados pelo aplicativo, sistema operacional ou servidor durante a operação.

Em resumo eles nos ajudam a identificar falhas.

No caso a pergunta estava informando:

> ...a classe PHP não aceita new...

O que leva a conjectura:

> **Sem o auxilio de um log ou uma mensagem como é possível decodificar essa informação?**

Cujo a resposta:

> **Seria possível decodificar o problema analisando o código da classe `Pesquisa`.**

O que nos leva a terceiro problema com a questão...

## Terceiro problema encontrado: Ausência do fulcro da questão.

Aqui realmente morreu a questão.

**Onde está a declaração da classe `Pesquisa` que é o centro de toda essa discussão?**

Todo questionamento não retórico busca um resposta.

A intenção da pergunta é levantar um fato, apresentando dados e informações que levem a investigação de soluções.

Mas como investigar uma solução para um problema que só é mencionado, mas que na verdade não está presente na pergunta e ferramentas que poderiam inferir sua presença(log de erros) também não estão presentes?

**É uma pergunta impossível de ser respondida da maneira que está sendo apresentada!**

Por isso o seu fechamento:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fora outros problemas, como a outra pergunta aglutinada sobre os selects que mereciam uma análise a parte pois se trata de outra pergunta inserida na mesma. Você pode até compreender como sendo uma mesma coisa, devido ao seu engajamento com o código, mas para nós que estamos lendo soa como duas questões distintas que seria melhor trabalhado em uma pergunta diferente. Talvez ao apresentar a declaração da classe `Pesquisa` as duas perguntas façam sentido como uma única. mas da forma que estão mesmo compartilhando o mesmo código há um abismo entre elas as tornando duas perguntas separadas.

--

## Como melhorar a pergunta?

- Primeiro passo seria restringir a pergunta ao problema com a classe `Pesquisa`. Tornando a pergunta concomitante ao título.
- Apresentar a declaração da classe `Pesquisa`.
- Apresentar o log de erros ou então a mensagem de erro do console.
- Enxugar o código  e evidenciar apenas as partes relacionadas com a lógica do problema, chamada Ajax, arquivo pesquisa.php e a declaração classe `Pesquisa`.

  Veja que só coloquei os passos de melhorar a pergunta, dando um leque de possibilidades. Mas caso você queira ajuda para reescrever sua questão é só informar aqui nos comentários que faço com satisfação aqui mesmo nessa resposta pois esse auxilio, ao meu ver,estaria dentro de nosso escopo aqui no META.

## Concluindo.

Foi injusta sua acusação contra a comunidade. Como pode ver a pergunta está cheia de falhas o que a impede de ser respondida e o fechamento não é punição, referência [A minha pergunta foi fechada. E agora?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7470/a-minha-pergunta-foi-fechada-e-agora). 
O fechamento é meio que a comunidade usa para salvaguardar a qualidade da informação contida no site. 
A pergunta ao ser fechada ela não desaparece ela fica em um estado de espera até que o seu autor a modifique. Feita a modificação, essa passa para um fila de análise onde os membros comunidade com reputação suficiente para participar da fila irão votar a reabertura da pergunta.

Uma pergunta mal feita deixada em aberto é um ambiente propício a leigos e neófitos emitam respostas absurdas, por não compreenderem a real problemática da questão, em busca de reputação fácil porque a pergunta não apresenta concorrência, mas não apresenta concorrência por que não há elementos suficientes para responde-lá.

Comment: Não há log de erros. O debugger simplesmente para. Não gerando falha, erro, aviso. Por isso ta me consumindo. Agora somente analisando  por meio da lógica, para achar onde está o erro. Como o debugger entra em suspenso, em outras palavras se recusa a criar a instancia da classe, não sei o porque isso ocorre. Como disse tenho um site no meu eclipse que faz a mesma coisa. Contudo ele funciona bem.

Comment: @FabianodeSouzaPereira deixei um comentário em sua pegunta. Ao editar e colocar o código da classe `Pesquisa` foi possível encontrar a fonte do problema, pelo menos acho que identifiquei a causa por isso indiquei um voto de reabertura, porém não depende só do meu voto para reabrir a questão, a comunidade irá avaliar se a edição clarificou a questão.

Comment: O fato de ter achado o erro não supre a falta de um [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Todos que vierem em seguida terão que analisar o código todo para sequer saber o que se trata (ou seja, a pergunta vai continuar servindo só para o autor. E se serve só para o autor, não serve para este site. A única solução possível seria remover todo o código e por o [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que já tinha sido solicitado.

Comment: Resumindo: olha a quantidade de ruído que a pergunta gerou para tentar ajudar. E no fim ainda não é possível ajudar de verdade. Vai contra o objetivo do site. Por isso mesmo sendo possível dar uma resposta, ela ainda não atende os critérios do site para ter uma.

Comment: O cara apagou a conta? Ele nem se deu ao trabalho de assumir que estava errado e pedir desculpas para o @Bacco e para comunidade pelas acusações infundadas.

Comment: @Maniero ou Bacco, Teria como recuperar a ultima edição da pergunta dele. Seria interessante fazer um EDIT mostrando o quanto ele foi arrogante ao presumir que a pergunta dele estava correta e a moderação estava errada.

Comment: @AugustoVasques sim, apagou, é sempre assim, é impressionante como é difícil de aparecer uma exceção para a regra. Sempre dá para recuperar o que for preciso, mas não acho que valha a pena, não vai mudar alguma coisa, sempre aparecerão pessoas assim, vão ignorar o que aconteceu no passado e vão repetir os erros.

Comment: @AugustoVasques simplesmente serve como reforço para o que a gente vem falando faz tempo. Sobre pedir desculpas, isso não faço nenhuma questão. Basta a pessoa entrar no ritmo do site e boa (sem trapaça, claro - tá cheio de gente que faz o maior auê e depois recria conta para fazer como se nada tivesse acontecido)

Comment: Quando li que me chamaram de arrogante. Refiz o perfil, e vou tentar de novo.  Embora, acredito que não vou mais fazer perguntas. Pois não sei faze-las bem feito. Mas a comunidade tem coisas que podem me ajudar. Pois toda pesquisa que faço no google sobre algo, sempre tem como primeiro resultado o stack overflow. Sobre desculpas, acho que não, pois a comunidade é inflexiva. Eu nesse momento estou sendo flexível, e reconhecendo que não sei fazer um pergunta aqui nesse foram. Uma dica. Antes de fechar uma pergunta, notifiquem o autor para altera-la. É melhor.

Comment: @Fabiano O site recebe em média mais de 100 perguntas por dia e em 2019 [quase 40% delas foram fechadas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8123/112052) - só não foi mais porque não há tantos usuários ativos fechando, senão ia passar de 50% fácil. Ou seja, podemos estimar mais de 50 perguntas com problemas, por dia. É inviável comentar em todas (ainda mais se tiver que escrever um texto como esse aí de cima pra cada uma). O ideal seria as pessoas lerem a [help] e demais links já mencionados, e aprender a fazer uma pergunta, antes de fazê-la de qualquer jeito. Isso sim seria melhor...

Comment: @Fabiano Outro ponto é que comentar explicando como melhorar a pergunta raramente tem funcionado. Geralmente a pessoa ignora, ou se revolta e xinga todo mundo. O seu caso é mais uma prova de que todos os comentários são em vão: veja a quantidade de texto aí em cima tentando te ajudar, explicando todos os problemas da pergunta, e ainda sim vc diz que não consegue fazer uma pergunta e resolveu desistir. Adiantou todas essas explicações? A gente vê tanta gente fazer como vc, que depois de todas as dicas ainda sim não entende, que chega uma hora que desanima, é melhor fechar sem comentar mesmo...

Comment: Olha fechar 40% das perguntas! Vocês perderam a cabeça? O problema de vocês é falta de moderadores. É isso. E estão se confundindo com o assunto. Minha opinião. Virou apenas como bater metas. " Nossa, temos muitas perguntas, não conseguimos gerenciar tudo, e agora. Já sei fecha todas as mal feitas ou as que faltaram algum detalhe!, Bora lá! .". Não to na pele de vocês, e talvez eu fizesse a mesma coisa que vocês estão fazendo. Contudo, a minha opinião é falta de pessoal. Se tivessem poucas perguntas com certeza não se importariam de dar mais atenção a elas. Nem fecharia, assim tão rápido.

Comment: @Fabiano Não existe "bater meta", essa é uma visão bem equivocada de sua parte. Imagine se pra cada pergunta não clara a gente tivesse que fazer um texto gigante como o que está acima, é inviável. Se há tantas perguntas fechadas, isso é consequência das pessoas não seguirem as instruções de como fazer uma boa pergunta. Aliás, os moderadores também têm fechado muitas perguntas, o problema não é falta deles (outro equívoco da sua parte). De qualquer forma, como vc mesmo disse, vc não está na nossa pele, e é uma pena, pois precisamos de ajuda pra manter o site organizado...

Comment: @Fabiano:"...Embora, acredito que não vou mais fazer perguntas. Pois não sei faze-las bem feito...", entenda que não é pessoal, essa é uma uma publicação técnica e todos nós estamos sujeitos a sermos contraditados tecnicamente. Eu peço em nome da comunidade, por favor traganos as suas dúvidas. Mas tenha em mente que todos nós a avaliaremos por um prisma técnico e eventualmente umas serão respondidas e outras fechadas por motivos técnicos....

Comment: ...Essas questões fechadas, você porá as reabrir. Aqui fechar e reabrir perguntas é uma coisa trivial no StackOverflow. O fechamento não é demérito, punição, desqualificação ou perseguição. O fechamento é apenas uma etapa que uma pergunta pode passar até obter uma resposta....

Comment: ...Quando tiver uma resposta fechada, você tem quatro alternativas: 1 - Avaliar o motivo e corrigir por si mesmo. 2 -No campo de comentário, abaixo da pergunta, você marcar os responsáveis pelo fechamento e pedir auxilio para melhorar a pergunta. 3 -  Você pode ir ao nosso [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=pt.stackoverflow.com) e pedir ajuda de forma interativa para clarificar a pergunta. 4 - Você vir aqui ao META solicitar o acompanhamento da comunidade a sua pergunta.

Comment: Você pode ter sentido que a comunidade é rígida. Eu concordo nós somos exigentes, mas com os membros mais ativos da comunidade nós somos muito mais rigorosos, exemplo eu mesmo em menos de um minuto eu tomei 10 downvotes, todos se identificaram e apresentaram o motivo, em uma resposta não por estar errada mas por se basear em um princípio equivocado e não achei isso ruim, na verdade até que gostei pois percebi que minha voz tem importância e valor na comunidade e por isso fiz essa análise a sua pergunta para que você percebesse que a comunidade não está contra você ou contra as suas perguntas..

Comment: ... nosso objetivo é ajudar o maior número de pessoas sendo uma fonte informações corretas e confiáveis, sendo que ninguém está sendo pago para isso, nenhum de nós é funcionário da SE. Nós que estamos aqui diariamente tanto os moderadores eleitos e os membros da comunidade ajudamos só porque gostamos de ajudar e nada mais....

Comment: ....Então eu peço a você e aos novos usuários que passarem por esses comentários que refaçam suas avaliações do que é o Stack Overflow e compreendam que o papel da Comunidade é zelar pela qualidade e integridade da informação veiculada nesse site e entendam que temos regras e protocolos rígidos para que sempre sejamos o melhor local, em língua Portuguesa, para se obter informações a respeito de programação.