# Não concordo em votação negativa sem justificativa

Tags: debate

Se vcs olharem as perguntas estão todas com votos negativos, vc acaba de postar ja tem voto negativo, aposto que é a mesma pessoa. Acho que se a pessoa vota negativo pelo menos tem que escrever um comentário e dizer pq está votando negativo se não quem fez o post nunca vai saber o motivo. Mudem isso pelo amor de deus. A comunidade é pra se ajudar não para apenas sairem votando de forma negativa em todos os topicos criados.

Comment: [O Stack Overflow não é um forum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/137387), veja em [Checklist de perguntas do Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8496/137387) uma  lista de verificações para fazer após escrever uma pergunta, veja também [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/137387). Entenda o funcionamento da comunidade lendo o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/137387) e leia o [FAQ da comunidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/699/faq-da-comunidade)

Comment: Olá  Desalex, não acho que estão acabando com nada, talvez esteja ruim para a sua perspectiva pessoal, mas para o que é real e necessário para manter a qualidade e do esforço que se espera de quem entende o que é [Exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) provavelmente não sofrerá com downvotes, mas se as perguntas raramente apresentam isso o downvote ali não é do mal, é um apontamento de que tem problema na pergunta, então dentre tantas perguntas mal elaboradas de diversas pessoas na verdade estamos indo muito bem, mesmo com isso.

Comment: ta ta bom, quer q eu edite o nome FORUM? vcs levam tudo ao pé da letra... me diz o que está errado na minha pergunta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/483225/como-passar-valor-de-object-para-propriedade-string-c
o que mais precisam que eu coloque ?

Comment: Devo ressaltar que apesar de vocÊ afirmar no titulo que pessoas estão acabando com o site, ainda sim o seu problema não é se as pessoas estão acabando com o site e sim um direcionamento as suas necessidades e não as necessidades do site, recomendo que mude o titulo e seja mais aberto em entender que o problema é com as suas postagens e perguntar aonde você pode melhora-las. Os links do Augusto acima já irão lhe ajudar. Obrigado por compreender.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento novamente vou responder como respondi pro hkotsubo, respeito sua opiniao mas nao concordo, quando vc diz:"é um apontamento de que tem problema na pergunta." Se tem um problema na pergunta pq a pessoa nao diz qual é esse problema? Vamos adivinhar o que está errado ?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento melhorou? rsrs

Comment: Sim, mas eu não estou falando disso, estou falando que o titulo da pergunta afirma uma coisa que não esta ocorrendo e que na verdade o problema que você esta reclamando é totalmente diferente do titulo dessa pergunta no META, o problema é **"aonde você pode melhorar suas perguntas pessoais"**, isso não tem nada haver com o resto do site, você tem que se focar em buscar dicas e ajuda para melhorar suas perguntas, assim vai obter os resultados que deseja. ;)

Comment: Desculpe o titulo foi um desabafo mesmo pq simplesmente TODAS as perguntas que faço eu acabo de fazer ja tem voto negativo e nenhuma resposta: Cade o feedback? pq nao comentam nem que seja pra dizer: Nao vou comentar pq sua pergunta está mal feita... Como vou adivinhar qual o problema? e sim, ja li e reli o checklist de como fazer pergunta e nao vejo que fiz algo errado

Comment: Então Desalex, agora o seu titulo é praticamente uma pergunta duplicata (acabaram de fechar como dup), porque debater downvotes já é algo que já foi muito debatido, deve ter uma 10 perguntas no META sobre isso, e existir downvote e não justifica-lo é totalmente aceitável como respondi a alguns anos: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4949/3635 ou então uma série de respostas: [downvote comentar is:answer](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=downvote+comentar+is%3Aanswer) --- isso é assunto já muito bem explicado, muitas duvidas suas futuras inclusive devem ter resposta no META.

Comment: Na boa a pergunta linkada é incompreensível. Faltam muitos detalhes, por exemplo você alega que lê uma API, mas qual o formato retornado por essa API, suscitando a pergunta se o retorno é "binário"(base64) ou texto(XML,JSON)? Lá em baixo você coloca *Obviamente no object é me retornado uma key e um value* mais existem diversas possibilidade de se representar objetos com Key/Value. Não tem como responder de você não nos definir a estrutura de retorno da chamada da API.

Comment: `e sim, ja li e reli o checklist de como fazer pergunta e nao vejo que fiz algo errado` esse é o motivo das pessoas não comentarem, é inócuo. As pessoas precisam aprender programar aos poucos, fazer coisas simples,, entender todos os conceitos, passar por cada etapa, quando ela pula tudo isso, vai tentando fazer coisas que ele não tem o entendimento mais básico ela não consegue expressar sobre o problemas e mesmo orientada ela não consegue resolver os problemas da pergunta, está muito além da capacidade dela. As pessoas cansaram de comentar. Principalmente com quem erra repetidas vezes.

Comment: @AugustoVasques mas pq precisa saber do retorno da api se é em json ou nao ? API foi somente um detalhe, a pergunta é simples, como passar valor vindo em uma propriedade object para uma string. Se eu nem mencionasse que estou lendo api faria diferença alguma, o object é um tipo de dado nao tem nada a ver com retorno de api, foi só um detalhe

Comment: Por isso que é melhor votar e não comentar. Foi só um teste comportamental eu não vou participar dessa discussão pois é inútil. As orientações já foram dadas.

Comment: kkkkkk ta certo, mais uma vez, vc disse que estava errado a pergunta da duvida e eu expus o pq que não está errado e vc disse, disse e nao disse nada na resposta...

Comment: Desalex, você pode acreditar que esteja 100% certo nos detalhamentos de suas perguntas, quando você pode na verdade não estar observando o problema de forma "ímpar", recomendo que leia os links que todos já passamos. Acho que a conversa entre todos chegou a um nível improdutivo, então por favor, siga as sugestões, reflita e tente acalmar, um tempo para refletir deve ajudar. Tenho quase certeza que até amanhã talvez você terá notado aonde precisa melhorar suas perguntas.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, leia:

- [Voto negativo sem justificativa é válido?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/652/112052) (*spoiler*: Sim!)
- [FAQ oficial do SOen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436): infelizmente só em inglês, mas ali tem todas as justificativas que explicam porque não é obrigatório comentar ao votar (nem positivo, nem negativo). Eu não concordo com 100% (talvez com 90%), mas é importante ler para entender porque é assim, e principalmente porque é improvável que a empresa mude o sistema para exigir comentários ao votar

Vale lembrar também que [o Stack Overflow **não** é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/112052).

Dito isso...

---

Você já viu as perguntas que são negativadas? Com exceção de um ou outro caso "injusto", a maioria são perguntas ruins e/ou fora do escopo:

- Preciso fazer um programa que faça X (e só)
- Qual o erro? [2000 linhas de código sem contexto nem explicação do que deveria fazer]
- e por aí vai...

A grande maioria delas falhou em um ou mais itens do [nosso checklist](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8496/112052). Provavelmente porque não fizeram o [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour), não leram a [Central de Ajuda](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), e nem o [Guia de Sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/112052).

Tudo bem, pode ser muita coisa para saber antes de fazer uma pergunta, e de fato é. Porque aqui é diferente de outros sites, onde você pode chegar escrevendo o que quer, do jeito que quer. Aqui é um pouco mais rígido que a média, e sim, se a pessoa não demonstrar esforço e fizer a pergunta de qualquer jeito, será negativada.

Então os votos só refletem a qualidade do que está sendo postado. Não tem nada a ver com "pessoas más querendo destruir o site" nem nada disso. Só estamos votando de acordo com o conteúdo que aparece. Se tivéssemos mais perguntas boas e dentro do escopo, teríamos menos perguntas negativadas e fechadas.

---

Outro ponto que muitos não levam em conta ao sugerir comentário obrigatório ao votar é que seria muito fácil "burlar" esta regra: bastaria eu comentar *qualquer* frase, mesmo que não faça sentido nem ajude a explicar o negativo - algo como "essa resposta é muito ruim", "não gostei, -1", etc. Como aliás, ironicamente  aconteceu nesta resposta:

[image: Comentário inútil]

Agora imagine se fosse na sua pergunta, no que um comentário desse ajudaria? <sup><sub><sub>*A propósito, o comentário acima foi removido justamente por ser irrelevante e não acrescentar nada à discussão.*</sub></sub></sup>

Isso porque comentar é opcional, imagina se fosse obrigatório, a quantidade de ruído que seria adicionada ao site.

---

Basicamente, a gente não comenta por vários motivos:

- já existe muito material disponível no site que explica como fazer uma boa pergunta dentro do escopo (admito que nem todos são facilmente acessíveis para quem não se dispuser a procurar, mas estão lá) - é inviável (e até meio "burro"/redundante) ter o retrabalho de reescrever tudo de novo em cada pergunta que aparece
- na maioria das vezes não é efetivo. Já perdi as contas das vezes que comentei e não adiantou nada, a pessoa não melhora a pergunta, ou se revolta e xinga a gente. Então depois de um tempo desanima
- tem também os que não gostam do comentário e começam a retaliar (dar negativos de vingança, etc), então muitos não comentam por receio, pra evitar ter esse stress todo

Então na verdade quem está estragando o site são as pessoas que acham que podem fazer perguntas de qualquer jeito, sem querer entender como o site funciona...

Comment: desculpa, respeito sua opiniao mas nao concordo com ela, varias vezes ja fiz pergunta SIMPLES, agora mesmo coloquei uma propriedade object em c# e a pergunta foi bem simples, em como faço para recuperar o valor de uma propriedade object e converter para string, o que mais precisa ser dito? quer que enfeite o topico tb ? está claro o que eu preciso, e me negativaram agora o pq ? se a pessoa tivesse comentado quem sabe eu saberia e pudesse melhorar...

Comment: @Desalex Infelizmente só quem votou pode dizer o porquê. Mas como eu disse, muita gente deixou deixou de comentar pelos motivos que já citei, e por causa disso acabamos chegando nessa situação chata em que ficamos sem saber pq levamos negativo. Eu tb não gosto e nem acho ideal, mas infelizmente o site chegou nesse ponto e não vejo uma solução simples...

Comment: Um exemplo bem ilustrativo: olha a [quantidade de texto](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8141/112052) pra explicar pro cara porque a pergunta dele não estava boa. É um esforço imenso, com a melhor das intenções: ajudá-lo a entender os problemas da pergunta e corrigi-los. Resultado: o cara [desistiu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8140/#comment31978_8141) ("*não vou mais fazer perguntas*") e ainda apagou a conta. Infelizmente essa é a regra, a gente explica, a pessoa não reconhece o problema e nada muda. Com o tempo isso desanima e as pessoas param de comentar...

Comment: Mas nao precisa fazer textao, é só ir direto ao ponto, algo como: detalhe mais tal coisa, coloque mais codigo, coloque a classe tal que está faltando, seja mais detalhista. Nao precisa fazer uma redação explicando minimos detalhes o q está errado.

Comment: Tem como postar o último parágrafo separado pra eu poder votar de novo?

Comment: @hkotsubo na verdade aqui estamos de novo gastando um tempo em repetir tudo...Podiamos estar negativando umas coisas, seria melhor pra comunidade :P . Pena que não posso dar bounty aqui, em especial pelo _"Então na verdade quem está estragando o site são as pessoas que acham que podem fazer perguntas de qualquer jeito, sem querer entender como o site funciona..."_

Comment: @Desalex Muitos novatos se dão bem aqui no site, se está tendo problema não é por ser novato. Você não entende o negativo, e tem um monte de gente tentando explicar. Você pode aproveitar isso ou não. Se se incomodou, não adianta querer imputar a mim, só falei verdades. Se amanha cair um cometa em cima de mim, as verdades serão as mesmas, só vai ser outra pessoa dizendo. Se entender, você tira melhor proveito da situação.

Comment: Sobre querer feedback, em nenhum momento disse que é errado. Só que isso já está explicado. E uma parte você já tem nos quadros de fechamento e no hover da seta do down. O que pode fazer, se quiser, é passar um link de uma pergunta e discutir sobre ela, aí dá pra ajudar a orientar.

Comment: Ainda, seus pontos permitem acesso ao chat da rede, pode muito bem discutir o assunto com tranquilidade. O que não dá, é esperar que as pessoas possam fazer muito mais do que já estao fazendo, meio mundo de pessoas parando pra orientar você. Agora, se uma resposta ou comentário não te agrada, é complicado fazer pergunta num lugar aberto né? Chamar de ignorante acho um pouco de ousadia, visto que quem não entendeu que negativo é só uma classificação é você. Nós já sabemos. E também sabemos que as vezes é chato, mas é pior ainda um positivo errado.

Comment: @Bacco eu passei o link no comentario do Luiz Felipe que comentou abaixo da minha postagem. Porem a pessoa disse que pq eu nao coloquei o retorno da API e eu respondi explicando que é pq nao tem a necessidade ja que a pergunta foi simples. Como eu faço pra passar o valor vindo em uma propriedade como object para uma propriedade string... oque mais isso tem que ser detalhado ?

Comment: @Bacco te peço desculpas pelo ignorante, mas vc viu a sua resposta como foi, com muita ironia!
"Então na verdade quem está estragando o site são as pessoas que acham que podem fazer perguntas de qualquer jeito, sem querer entender como o site funciona..."  desculpa eu nao acho que fiz pergunta de qualquer jeito, acho que está bem claro o que eu precisava, mas enfim, nao tem problema eu saio da comunidade sem problema algum

Comment: @Desalex eu só repeti o que estava na resposta pq concordo, pq eu vivo tendo que lidar com isso diariamente (e nem se refere especificamente a você, e sim a um problema maior). O que posso dizer é: q se tomar um negativo injusto, os positivos compensarão. Se vc pensar sempre em como melhorar (mesmo que ache que já está bom), todos ganham. E se mesmo assim não resolver, é tentar estudar o site mais e mais até pegar o jeitão. Não tem como ser diferente. Negativar ou fechar um post, pra quem se preocupa com o site, não é legal, mas precisa. Gostoso é poder positivar, mas depende do conteúdo

Comment: @Desalex você fez a pergunta de qualquer jeito e o fato de não achar mostra que tudo isso é improdutivo, está gastando o tempo de todos sem que nada útil saia daqui, nem pra você e nem para outras pessoas. Desde o início chegou com suposições falsas, tom acusatório, escreve sem pensar antes, fica repetindo as mesmas coisas fora de contexto. Entenda que o negativo que teve lá foi porque a pergunta não tem nem pé nem cabeça, você está fazendo coisas que não entende e por isso não consegue sequer enxergar problema, e tentar ajudar só dará problema. Toda orientação foi dada e está sendo inócua.

Comment: @Maniero exatamente, por isso mesmo, se eu entendesse eu nao precisava perguntar aqui pedindo por ajuda. Quem faz suposições falsa ta sendo vc, vc dizer que a pergunta é sem pé nem cabeça sem mostrar onde está a falha: Como passar valor de uma propriedade object para string? Meu deus o que mais precisa ser explicado ai ? "tom acusatorio" aonde que acusei alguem de algo? falei que votaram e nao justificaram o pq, somente isso! A minha pergunta é do mesmo nivel de por exemplo: como converter string pra int. Nao tem necessidade alguma em ficar detalhando até pq nao tem como!

Comment: @Desalex Só pra concluir, a sua pergunta fala sobre negativos sem comentários de maneira geral, por isso respondi também de maneira mais geral, sem focar em um caso específico. Mas se quer discutir especificamente sobre uma pergunta em particular, sugiro que [abra outra discussão](/questions/ask) com a tag [pergunta-específica] e um link para a pergunta em questão, além de apresentar os seus argumentos que expliquem pq você acha que o fechamento foi incorreto. Assim a comunidade pode responder, votar, etc, e focando a discussão no caso específico, sem misturar os assuntos

Comment: Analisei a pergunta do usuário enumerei os motivos porque a pergunta é irrespondível. Quatro dias depois ainda não foi tomada nenhuma atitude visando a melhoria da mesma. Nesse intervalo outra pergunta também foi questionada por outro usuário, o usuário também adotou a mesma postura agressiva. Fiz a [análise](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116571/discussion-on-question-by-isaac-selecionar-o-ultimo-numero-via-regex-ao-identifi)  também não houveram  mudanças. É desgastante, pois é sempre um leigo que vem ao site extravasar e nisso pessoas que realmente são especialistas vão abandonando.