# Você está feliz no SOpt?

Tags: debate, comunidade, stackexchange

Leia o título e responda a si mesmo: você está feliz com a comunidade do StackOverflow em Português hoje?

Se sua resposta é não, saiba que também existem pessoas que não estão. Talvez a culpa não seja sua, nem nossa. Talvez.

Ultimamente, tenho visto muitas pessoas postando desabafos, reclamações e algumas [estatísticas ruins](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8110/feliz-ano-novo-2020). No final, acabo vendo situações que ficamos contra nós mesmos. Não existem líderes ou deuses quando todos estão insatisfeitos com o sistema.

A qualidade das perguntas caiu muito. Nossas regras se mantiveram. Houve um colapso de adaptação as mesmas. Seria este um problema de ignorância? Se for, é por parte de quem?

Muitos confundem o nosso propósito. Estamos aqui para ajudar, mas você deverá se adaptar. Nossos fundamentos e regras foram escritos com um protocolo e filosofia voltada ao `Pergunte e Responda`. [Não somos um fórum.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2068/o-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs-%C3%A9-um-f%C3%B3rum)

Vejo uma preocupação intensa por parte da comunidade mais estabelecida, como os moderadores, principalmente com a qualidade do nosso armazém de conteúdo e conhecimento. Está apodrecendo, e estamos sem ferramentas, sem demandas, sem o que fazer. Não temos a ajuda necessária quando estamos lidando com uma empresa centralizada que não parece ligar muito para a situação.

Tivemos que fazer um [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs), mas parece que não resolveu muita coisa. Acreditamos que foi a preguiça de ler nossas regras, então fizemos uma [versão curta dele](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8089/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-sopt-vers%C3%A3o-curta). Não vi melhorias de nenhuma amplitude.

Esse é o reflexo da nossa própria preocupação. Os resultados são produto da incógnita que estou discutindo nesta postagem.

### O que será do StackOverflow em Português nos próximos anos?

Faço-me essa pergunta sempre que me deparo com uma situação desta. Não consigo imaginar um bom fim. Estamos rumo a um desastre, é o que mostram as estatísticas e principalmente a manifestação da comunidade de todas categorias.

Outras perguntas que são relacionadas incluem: "Até quando vamos insistir?", "Até que ponto o *lixo* chegará?" e "O que acontecerá?".

### Onde está o erro?

Não é preciso debater se o atual modelo de moderação em relação à alta demanda de perguntas de baixa qualidade é suficiente, **porque não é**. Infelizmente, não somos nós que decidimos como funcionarão os protocolos de moderação do site. Será que o erro é de quem decide como nós lidamos e moderamos a comunidade?

Sim, são muitas perguntas, e todas voltam a este mesmo assunto e preocupação. Por suma, **você está feliz com o StackOverflow em Português hoje?** Como podemos melhorar? O que nós podemos fazer para evitar um colapso no final? Aliás, o que você, membro da comunidade, já fez por nós hoje?

Comment: Tem muita coisa que não concordo, fico preocupado com crescente queda na qualidade das perguntas e resposta. Fico chateado quando os usuários esquecem que esse é um site técnico, onde todos estamos sujeitos a ser contraditados tecnicamente e passam a se comportarem como se fosse uma rede social levando as coisas para o lado pessoal querendo ter razão no grito. Mas fico feliz que mesmo dispondo de poucos recursos para reverter a situação atual, a comunidade conta com membros valiosos compromissados com a qualidade de nosso conteúdo, a melhoria e a manutenção do site. Bola pra frente.

Comment: Muitas pessoas não estão felizes com a SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342335/140010

Comment: Vocês precisam ler isto para entender um pouco mais o que está acontecendo com a SE https://twitter.com/gortok/status/1217838950494228480

Comment: Minha infelicidade não é com o SOpt respectivamente, mas sim com a equipe da Stack Exchange e as ações que andam fazendo ultimamente

Comment: @riki481 Você pode exemplificar algumas ações? Não pergunto por mal, eu estive "numa caverna" nos últimos meses...

Comment: Quem está feliz nas comunidades do Stack Exchange? lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A infelicidade sempre vem do fato das coisas não estarem como se deseja. Seria bom que tudo fosse como queremos, mas não tem como ser assim porque cada pessoa quer algo diferente e temos que respeitar, dentro de certos limites, que isto aconteça; então, para alguém ser feliz, temos que sermos infelizes de alguma forma. Algumas pessoas lidam melhor com isso do que outras. Em geral as que lidam melhor são as que foram treinadas pelos seus pais desde o começo que a vida é assim. Também lida melhor que cede mais de forma natural, nem sempre isso é bom.

Ceder foi o que muitos pais fizeram para serem amados por seu filhos. Eles viam os filhos felizes e isso os deixava felizes. Mal sabiam que estavam criando uma armadilha pra eles. Tem muitos casos, nem todo mundo responde igual, mas é fato que gerações mais novas são folgadas e só querem ter na mão tudo o que desejam, e se frustram muito quando isto não acontece. O narcisismo passou a ser enorme e elas não têm espírito de comunidade, só querem o seu.

Redes sociais têm reforçado isto, e mesmo pessoas de outras gerações passaram a se perguntar "mas pode isso?". Ficar impondo suas vontades é muito atraente. Todo mundo quer fazer isto. Um dos motivos que as redes sociais funcionam e não funcionam tanto é justamente que pode todo mundo falar o quer e todo mundo será julgado por isso. Redes sociais têm bem poucas regras explícitas, então tudo pode acontecer.

Em ambientes mais técnicos onde há um objetivo profissional e se busca construir conhecimento e evoluir pessoas, as regras precisam ser mais claras e mais impostas. Não tem evolução sem disciplina.

Fica pior quando algumas pessoas que entram em uma comunidade técnica que preza pela qualidade não só foi educada a querer tudo para si e não olhar para o que está à sua volta, e foram pouco treinadas para reagir bem quando são confrontadas, mas também a edução formal, a escolaridade de muitos que entram aqui é baixa, talvez pelo mesmo problema: ela não queria ser contrariada. Os professores cansaram de sofrer tentando ensinar algo e serem contestados por isso, até que simplesmente dão notas para todos serem felizes assim.

Tem também os professores que já passaram por isso e os que nem conseguem ensinar. Tinha uma época que se falava, até preconceituosamente, que, se a pessoa tentou tudo na vida e não conseguiu, ela vai ser policial. Hoje se fala isso de professores. Tem exceções, mas a triste verdade é que isto acontece muito. Ser motorista de Uber paga mais e dá menos dor de cabeça que dar aula.

Então as pessoas que esperam aqui soluções para seus problemas específicos, e que as pessoas se esforcem para dar-lhes o que desejam mesmo que ela não faça sua parte, porque ela está acostumada assim, e se não vão conseguir, tornar-se-ão infelizes aqui.

As pessoas que gostariam ter pessoas com boa vontade, com um mínimo de conhecimento (não de programação), com comprometimento com sua própria evolução, que seja atenciosa e grata por estar recebendo uma ajuda valiosa com quem se dispões ajudar gratuitamente, acabam ficando infelizes aqui por não encontrar isto.

Portando se buscarmos felicidade aqui fica complicado. As pessoas que vão percebendo isto vão se afastando como aconteceu com inúmeras pessoas que faziam este local espetacular. Alguns saíram de vez, outros diminuíram muito a participação.

Também pode ter tornado este local mais infeliz o fato de tudo ter se tornado politicamente correto. No começo aqui e, principalmente no SOen, você tinha muito bom humor (sem ser ofensivo) e ajudava na felicidade. Hoje não pode mais, as pessoas ficaram chatas. Então o ambiente se tornou menos feliz. Tudo que as pessoas procuram traz consequências, nem sempre as que elas desejam.

Como membros de comunidade, acabamos tendo que lidar com isso. Como muitos dos que são ativos no site não são bestas alopradas que querem tudo do seu jeito, acabamos nos adaptando a isto, mesmo não sendo o ideal.

Tornar as pessoas felizes nunca foi objetivo do site. Não dá para brigar por isto. E não tem como fazer para todos. Brigamos pelo objetivo principal do site que é produzir **conteúdo de qualidade** para **todos** aproveitarem, **sem ruído** que se encontra em outros lugares.

Infelizmente somos mais felizes quando estamos circundados de pessoas que fazem o mesmo que queremos, que pensam igual, quando diminuímos a real diversidade (não a que usa o termo equivocadamente). Mas existe momento para aceitar tudo porque isso provoca inovação, e existe momento para termos um fluxo unitário que facilita o caminho. Diversidade é ótimo quando você quer algo novo e aceita o ruído que isto causa. Aqui sempre foi objetivo evitar o ruído, buscar o que já é consagrado, por isso não é um fórum.

Um fórum é bom para criar conhecimento novo. Por isso não gosto de usar o termo mesmo para os sites que são *help desk*. Pra mim o máximo é o site que cria conhecimento novo, mas é bem complicado administrar isso.

A felicidade é difícil de ser atingida porque o indivíduo fica feliz com seus desejos atendidos, o que é impossível. A anarquia tenta isso, mas é complicado porque a liberdade do outro sempre interferirá na sua liberdade.

O segredo da felicidade é administrar bem seus desejos e frustrações. Não é fácil. No mundo ideal todos aprenderíamos isto de uma forma ou de outra.

## Pontos específicos

Eu acho que a ignorância é o problema das pessoas. É duro, mas é isto. E ignorância no sentido amplo. Ignorância das novas gerações ou das antigas que se comportam da mesma forma. É culpa da indústria que, na falta de profissionais, tentam atrair pessoas que não tem condições de fazer coisas simples na vida e tentam fazer coisas complicadas. E elas são assim porque escolheram ou foram induzidas a não se comprometerem com o que fazem. Não foram ensinadas aprender.

Isto causa frustração nas pessoas que podem ajudar e no fim passamos enxugar gelo. E aí não temos tempo para cuidar do que realmente importa porque temos que lidar com o ruído. E se começa dar espaço para quem gosta do ruído, deturpa o objetivo original do site que me fez estar aqui e fez muita gente entrar (a mudança foi afastando as pessoas qualificadas, e pra ser honesto foi diminuindo a motivação. Eu mesmo não faço mais com o afinco que fazia, por causa da frustração). De certa forma acho que não desapego porque investi muito tempo e não quero ver tudo o que fiz misturado com uma parte com tão pouco valor.

Também é bem frustrante ver que até o conteúdo antigo não é mais valorizado como era antes.

O objetivo do guia na verdade era melhorar nada, mas simplificar o processo, já que não tem ferramenta melhor para instruir a pessoa do que está errado. Inclusive ele não substitui uma ajuda mais específica que eu não tenho tempo para fazer, já faço muito, ou não?

É claro que o resultado está sendo um desastre pelo objetivo da qualidade. Se fosse decidido que isto não importa então tudo seria considerado normal, em outros locais a mesma situação não seria um desastre.

Por isso eu já questionei se não era o caso de mudar o objetivo. Eu não gosto e não sei o que eu faria neste caso, mas é um questionamento válido. Eu tentei mudar algumas coisas, mas não teve uma aceitação clara. E olha que ainda era dentro do objetivo de produzir conteúdo para todos e não indo em direção da ajuda específica. Se nem essa parte vai bem, imagina a parte que vai contra o objetivo original.

Eu só vejo piora, eu ainda estou debatendo o assunto, mas estou cansando. Vamos resistir até onde cada um aguentar. Eu tenho um motivo muito específico de não ter parado de vez. Já não faço mais com o gosto de antes. O groso do que o SOpt foi pra mim aconteceu no passado.

Podemos decidir os protocolos de moderação do site sim, todos juntos. A moderação não pode fazer o que bem entende. Ela faz o que a comunidade quer. Claro que se não concordar pode sair. Eu fui eleito para algo, se mandarem eu fazer algo diferente eu posso não querer mais. Claro que há adaptação de acordo com o momento.

E claro que comunidade é quem participa. Comunidade não é quem aparece vez ou outra pra perguntar ou responder algo e não participa de mais nada. Quando a pessoa só tem crítica quando ela teve seu interesse contrariado, ela não está agindo como comunidade. Comunidade é quem tem compromisso. Não faria sentido a pessoa dar uma opinião, as pessoas seguem o que ela quer e ela some. Principalmente porque a opinião dela não será embasada, se ela não entende o funcionamento do site.

Comment: "Tinha uma época que se falava, até preconceituosamente, que, se a pessoa tentou tudo na vida e não conseguiu, ela vai ser policial. Hoje se fala isso de professores. Tem exceções, mas a triste verdade é que isto acontece muito." ... Hoje isso se chama "Coach" rs

Answer (score 0):

Claro que não estamos felizes!    Tenho evitado responder questões aqui... Tenho preferido responder no [stackoverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDsFI.png) na versão inglês, as respostas são menos agredidas e mais valorizadas lá. Aqui pelo mínimo que seja alguém aplica um `downvote`, principalmente mirando os iniciantes. A pessoa aplica o voto `negativo` e não diz nada, não explica o motivo nem nada. Acha que está contribuindo horrores!   Esta versão em Português me parece mais uma `reunião de egos` prontos para esmagar quem estes consideram ináptos ou incapazes para o nível exigente de seus gloriosos conhecimentos técnicos e inteligência. Quanta gente desiste por isso? Estão matando o `SOpt` (stackoverflow português)! Bora ajudar quem está precisando! Corrigir a conduta e melhorar a pergunta é tarefa da moderação... penalizar sem explicar o motivo, sem dar um suporte antes é agressividade pura. Soft skills deve vir antes de hard skills, reflitam.

> Estão matando o `SOpt`!

**Atualização!**:

Menos de 1 ano depois, sigo acreditando que o caminho é ensinar... Olha aqui a evolução. ​ Mais alguém teve pré-acesso neste período Alpha?

Já viram como são as resposta da **IA**?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Muito interessante as respostas das pesquisas.

Meus votos de muita prosperidade neste ano!

Comment: São sempre as mesmas reclamações e nós damos sempre as mesmas respostas para esse tipo de publicação. É muito infeliz ter que escrever isso e ler isso. Entendo que esteja desgostando da comunidade, mas tenho certeza que a sua visão sobre ela está errada. Talvez entender o [tour] já é o primeiro passo.

Comment: Corrigir e melhorar não é só papel da moderação, [é papel de todos](/q/8437/112052). Só que a maioria não está fazendo sua parte: não leem a Central de Ajuda, ignoram as orientações (por isso muitos desistiram de tentar ajudar, pq quase nunca adianta), e ainda jogam a culpa nos outros (na moderação, nos usuários "tóxicos", etc). São esses que estão matando o site. Já a meia dúzia que ainda se importa fica aqui enxugando gelo, tomando pedrada e no final ainda leva a culpa...

Comment: E só lembrando que [não é obrigatório comentar ao votar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8788/112052) <-- leia, pois mesmo que não concorde, é importante pra entender porque é assim

Comment: Não demonstrou fatos, nada concreto, nem proposta de melhoria?. Responder faz sentido pra quem participa, não para quem vem a passeio. Desculpe a sinceridade, mas parece não fazer muita idéia do que é o site (tem tempo de corrigir). Pergunta  bem formulada é obrigação de quem posta. **A comunidade adora novatos, ninguem gosta é de desleixados**. Quem fica no negativo são só os que largam post sem arrumar. Se vê como "penalização", ´precisa ler o [tour] e a [help] para entender que voto é a classificação que traz a confiança que outros sites não tem. Penalizar seria se não tivesse conserto.

Comment: Agora, eu te pergunto, pra reflexão de todos nós: com o que você pode contribuir de fato com o acervo do site, de forma que possamos votar positivo? Se o padrão adotado nas postagens for o mesmo dos posts que se queixou de negativos, o site teria o sucesso e a procura que tem? Sempre lembrando, no espírito do site, que pode [edit] sua postagem e melhorar argumentos e apresentar algo concreto, que o post é reavaliado (da mesma forma que no site principal). Sobre o negativo, da mesma forma que o positivo, aqui não é "like", nem rede social, é classificação de utilidade.

Comment: "Tenho preferido responder no stackoverflow na versão inglês" você tem uma outra conta? Na sua tem uma única resposta em 2021, mais nada. Reforço a ideia de que precisa elaborar sobre a morte do SOpt, que eu concordo, mas qual a causa? Qual sua solução?

Comment: Entendo o ponto de vista de cada um de vocês e talvez vocês tenham razão. E toda esta certeza e razão pode estar contribuindo para a frustração de muitos membros da comunidade, acreditem. A mecânica do `SOpt` está muito mais rígida do que a própria `SOen`. Em relação ao meu perfil, apesar de o sistema indicar `Novo contribuidor`, não sou nada novo. Só me afastei mesmo e cada vez que tento me aproximar a decepção é a mesma. Meu score na `SOen` está 4x maior do que o daqui e também não sou recente por lá, mas me sinto muito gratificado cada vez que colaboro por lá, isso não ocorre aqui.

Comment: @EvertonCosta sobre questão de ego, claramente tem algum ferido, mas isso mostra que o sistema está funcionando ainda. Repele o que não acrescenta, atrai o que é bom. O que está "matando o SOpt" são usuários que não acrescentam. O que não deixou morrer até hoje foi a comunidade participativa, que é quem filtra o conteúdo em vez de usar aqui como rede social. O bom é que esse tipo de post ajuda a cercar o problema: o descompromisso (de usuários que vem por turismo, e de a empresa não ter as mesmas prioridades de quem "inventou" o site). Pra moderação é trabalhoso conciliar isso, mas necessário.

Comment: Estamos no aguardo de alguma edição concreta para podermos dizer "esse pessoal vai trazer conteúdo bom, então vamos levar a sério o que eles dizem, analisar o modo de ver etc". Se isso vier, a comunidade agradece. Se ficar só na "pedrada", ao menos ajuda localizar melhor a parte do "ego". Ficamos no aguardo. (nota a leitores que não estejam entendendo o "desafio": temos uma "tese" consolidada na comunidade - vide outras discussões - de que em geral esse tipo de crítica sempre vem de onde não tem participação e proposta, mas sempre ficamos esperando ver se "dessa vez vai ser diferente").

Comment: Curioso que se vc acompanhar o [Meta do SOen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) e o [Meta principal da rede](https://meta.stackexchange.com), vai ver que o mesmo tipo de reclamação aparece por lá também (e muito disso é apagado sem dó). O que acontece é que os sites em inglês possuem um volume **muito** maior que o SOpt, então as reclamações ficam diluídas, e muita gente acaba tendo a percepção errada de que não acontece. Além disso, como o volume é muito maior, o pessoal não dá conta de moderar tudo e muita coisa passa batida, por isso é bem mais fácil ter mais pontos lá