# Por que não é obrigatório comentar ao dar voto negativo, e por que sugestões para que seja obrigatório não são bem recebidas?

Tags: suporte, faq, comentários, voto-contra

> A publicação como um todo é a tradução livre de [*Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/11379709) publicado por [Pekka](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/187606/pekka).

Às vezes, meu post recebe votos negativos sem explicação sobre o que fiz de errado. Pior ainda, às vezes eu só recebo comentários ácidos!

Acho que isso é ruim principalmente para usuários novos, que podem pensar que não são bem-vindos pelos veteranos. As regras do Stack Overflow são difíceis de entender, especialmente por novatos, e votos negativos parecem agressivos e desmotivantes.

Muitas ideias para mudar isso já foram propostas, incluindo:

- Todo voto negativo deve vir acompanhado de um comentário obrigatório
- Votos negativos devem ter um comentário obrigatório e *anônimo*
- Votos negativos devem ter um motivo, escolhido em um menu *drop-down*
- O *primeiro* voto negativo deve ter um comentário obrigatório
- Votos negativos que forem acompanhados de um comentário não custariam pontos a quem votou
- …e muitas outras variações

Entretanto, sempre que alguém sugere alguma dessas mudanças no Meta, ela é imediatamente rejeitada e (ironicamente) recebe vários negativos sem explicação!

**Por que todas essas ideias são rejeitadas?**

Seria porque as pessoas aqui são "malvadas", "mesquinhas", "tóxicas", "*trolls*", etc, que odeiam a tudo e todos, e *não querem* que os novatos se sintam bem-vindos?

[image: "Troll Norueguês", de Ivar Rodningen]
<sup>[(Fonte da imagem: "Troll Norueguês", de Ivar Rodningen)](http://avax.news/pictures/127383)</sup>

[Retornar para o índice da FAQ](/q/699)

Comment: A conversa foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139143/discussion-on-question-by-augusto-vasques-por-que-nao-e-obrigatorio-comentar-ao) - quem quiser acompanhar pode utilizar o link fornecido.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Obrigar que os votos negativos sejam acompanhados por um comentário parece uma boa ideia à primeira vista, e muitos aqui gostariam de ver os novos usuários obterem todas as informações necessárias para fazer perguntas que se encaixem no modelo do site! Ao contrário da "crença popular", a maioria dos usuários aqui são [gentis](https://lifehacker.com/why-you-should-be-kind-instead-of-nice-1846124841) e querem ajudar, e não gostam de "atirar nos novatos" negativando as perguntas destes para que eles se sintam mal. (**Na verdade, esse não é o propósito nem a intenção dos votos negativos!**)

O que não é comumente entendido ou mesmo imediatamente óbvio para o observador casual é que o Stack Overflow se tornou uma grande cidade. Embora as grandes cidades possam oferecer enormes benefícios (para o Stack Overflow, a analogia é uma densa concentração de experiência), elas também enfrentam problemas exclusivos relacionados à falta de dimensionamento de recursos, incluindo tráfego, congestionamento e poluição. Para sobreviver, as grandes cidades precisam de regras diferentes das pequenas vilas, e como resultado tendem a serem mais anônimas, "duras" e "frias". A importância de cada indivíduo diminui em relação ao todo.

[image: Atta Kenare, Getty Images]
<sup>[(Fonte da imagem: Atta Kenare, Getty Images)](https://auto.howstuffworks.com/air-pollution-from-cars.htm)</sup>

[Votos negativos são importantes para a saúde do site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-downvoting), e obrigar um voto a ter um comentário dificultaria *muito* o seu funcionamento como é hoje—ao ponto de potencialmente destruí-lo. Simplesmente não é viável, por vários motivos que veremos a seguir. É por isso que, embora esta seja uma sugestão frequente, ela é geralmente rejeitada e negativada.

Eis os principais argumentos que explicam porque não é uma boa ideia:

- **Votos negativos são, antes de tudo, um sistema de classificação de conteúdo**. Em vez de servir ao *autor* da postagem, [os votos negativos são uma forma de comunicar a *futuros visitantes*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250181) que a pergunta ou resposta não é útil ou interessante. Se alguém quiser deixar um comentário para o autor, isso sempre pode ser feito, *independente* do sistema de votação (só não peça para os outros usuários fazerem isso por você).
- **Na grande maioria dos casos, nada precisa ser esclarecido**. O *tooltip* na seta de voto negativo já explica o que ele significa, tanto para perguntas quanto para respostas. Em muitos casos, o "comentário" do *tooltip* já explica adequadamente a lógica por trás do voto, e um comentário adicional seria apenas ruído desnecessário.
- **Qualquer regra poderia ser facilmente burlada**, seja comentando qualquer coisa sem sentido (como "*fvayiuehj4839fdsa*") ou algo que não acrescenta nada como "*essa resposta é muito ruim*". Detectar e impedir todos estes comentários através de ferramentas de moderação é inviável em um site com milhares de usuários.
- **À primeira vista pode não parecer, mas ao votar negativo, estamos prestando um serviço ao site, e dificultar o voto prejudicaria a ferramenta mais importante que temos para o controle da qualidade do site.** Votar é fácil e simples, sem "atritos", pois o site foi pensado para ser exatamente assim! Os votos separam o bom conteúdo do ruim, e faz o primeiro ficar mais visível. *Isso é essencial para que a plataforma funcione, mesmo que às vezes pareça "maldade".* Se foi dado um voto errado—o que pode acontecer—a ideia é que "o coletivo" corrija o problema. Um único voto não é nada, o que importa é a *soma* de todos os votos, e é por isso que o site só mostra esse valor.
- **Escala.** O Stack Overflow em Português recebe, em média, dezenas de perguntas por dia. Muitas delas são de baixa qualidade ou não se encaixam no escopo do site. Não há atualmente usuários ativos em número suficiente para dar suporte individual a cada uma dessas perguntas (há muitos usuários registrados, mas a maioria não faz esse trabalho de [moderação comunitária](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8437/112052)). Dar esta ajuda individualizada seria um gasto muito grande de tempo e esforço (lembrando que os usuários são todos voluntários que participam de graça no seu tempo livre).
- **Se ficar mais difícil dar um voto negativo (pois agora será exigido um comentário), então também deveria ser igualmente mais difícil votar positivo.** O sistema usa votos negativos **e** positivos para separar o conteúdo "bom" do "ruim". Se o voto negativo sem comentário é um problema, então o positivo sem comentário também é, já que há casos de conteúdo de qualidade duvidosa recebendo positivos, indicando—erroneamente—que aquilo é considerado "bom".
- **A documentação sobre [como fazer uma boa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) está disponível para qualquer um que se disponha a lê-la**. As regras do Stack Overflow são muitas, e reconhecidamente mais complicadas do que a média dos sites internet afora, mas de qualquer forma há muito material escrito a respeito; temos um [*checklist*](/q/8496) que explica como fazer uma boa pergunta (baseado nas [recomendações de Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), o [usuário #1 do Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)). Aqui no site também há guias sobre [como responder de maneira adequada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), além do extenso porém necessário [Guia de Sobrevivência](/q/8045/) (que todos deveriam ler).
- **Comentar ao dar voto negativo pode trazer consequências ruins, como ["votos de vingança"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=negativos+em+s%C3%A9rie) e até mesmo perseguição fora do site.** Muitos usuários mais experientes [podem te contar situações](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/353978) nas quais já comentaram ao votar negativo, mas pararam de fazê-lo devido à retaliação dos usuários que receberam o voto. Mesmo quando todos se mantêm calmos e racionais, comentar sobre o voto quase sempre leva à extensas discussões, que muitas vezes acabam desvirtuando do tópico principal, e isso é algo que procuramos evitar.
- **O Stack Overflow (tanto a comunidade quanto a empresa) está trabalhando muito para deixar o site mais amigável e receptivo.** Nos últimos anos, vimos muitas discussões, [iniciativas](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/07/20/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/?_ga=2.28893247.2089068709.1634886060-142443118.1634886060), alterações na interface do usuário, [atualizações](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182812/introducing-a-brand-new-consolidated-help-center) e renovações da Central de Ajuda, experimentos como a [mentoria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357198/mentorship-research-project-results-wrap-up/) e muito mais—tudo com o objetivo de proporcionar uma experiência inicial melhor, sem perder o compromisso com a qualidade. Na verdade, muitos veteranos acham até que a empresa responsável pelo site está dando ênfase *demais* na parte de tornar o site mais amigável, a fim de atrair mais tráfego (ou seja, mais dinheiro), e deixando de lado a qualidade. Mas independente deles estarem certos ou errados, não dá para dizer que nada está sendo feito. É um problema bem complicado de resolver.
- **Não há espaço para todos.** [Sempre haverá mais pessoas fazendo perguntas do que dando respostas de qualidade.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/?_ga=2.24250681.2089068709.1634886060-142443118.1634886060) Você não pode sobrecarregar os que respondem, permitindo uma quantidade enorme de perguntas ruins e/ou fora do escopo—isso destruiria todo o sistema, e acabaria impedindo que qualquer pergunta fosse respondida. Não conseguir uma resposta no Stack Overflow não é o fim do mundo; muitos usuários têm perguntas que gostariam de fazer no site, [mas não o fazem porque sabem que são se encaixaria no escopo](/a/1950). Para isso há outros sites disponíveis na internet, e não há a perspectiva de se aceitar *qualquer* tipo de pergunta por aqui.

## Então não tem como mudar?

Como já explicado, os votos, tanto positivos quanto negativos—e seu funcionamento atual, sem exigir comentários—são parte fundamental da estrutura básica do site, e da forma como ele foi pensado para funcionar. Qualquer mudança nesse mecanismo básico têm consequências bem mais profundas do que a maioria das sugestões usuais conseguem enxergar.

Qualquer proposta de alteração neste mecanismo teria que ir **muito** além do "*não gosto*"/"*não concordo*", e precisaria levar em conta tudo que foi dito acima. Teria que ser algo que não altere o funcionamento básico do site (ou que pelo menos não cause tanta disrupção), ou precisaria de uma boa justificativa para mexer em algo tão fundamental—neste caso, a "filosofia" do site mudaria tanto que precisaria de ótimos motivos para tal mudança.

E lembre-se que uma mudança neste nível não depende só da comunidade concordar. A principal parte a ser convencida é a [empresa dona do site](https://stackoverflow.co/), pois é a única que pode implementar tal mudança. Vale lembrar também que o Stack Overflow em Português é apenas um dentre os [mais de 180 sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) da rede Stack Exchange, então sua proposta de mudança teria que levar isso em conta: tem que ser uma justificativa **muito** boa para mudar em tantos sites diferentes. Ou mesmo que seja para mudar apenas no SOpt, ainda sim teria que ter um bom motivo para que somente este site seja a exceção.

Pode ser que um dia mude? Bem, dado o histórico dos últimos anos, a empresa tem feito mudanças de forma unilateral, sem se importar com o que as comunidades acham, então sim, pode ser que um dia ela decida mudar de repente. Mas enquanto isso não acontece, a única forma de propor mudanças é o que já foi explicado. **E como é algo que envolve toda a rede, não só o Stack Overflow em Português, o lugar mais indicado para fazê-lo seria [aqui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), e com o cuidado de não duplicar alguma discussão já existente.**

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144668/discussion-on-answer-by-augusto-vasques-por-que-nao-e-obrigatorio-comentar-ao-da).